# Basic program which opens/writes to a txt randomly crashes/doesn't open

Tags: c++, fstream

I understand this code is very **very** badly optimised, and it is quite likely very hard to understand, but my issue is, that every now and then, approximately every 20 times I compile (I use Code::Blocks IDE and MinGW compiler) the file won't open and say that access is denied. It is also worth noting that I can *never* boot the file from the plain exe, only through the Build&Run/Run of Code::Blocks
The program opens a text file, named notes.txt, and allows you to write, read, or delete information in the text file.

**EDIT** It is also important to note, that when I try to boot the file from the straight executable, I get the error message "libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing from your computer"
This error has fixes online, which involve moving all .dll from the bin folder of my compiler, into the root of my executable. This fix works in making the program start, but the program crashes immediately after. This makes me believe it could be a compiler configuration error. Some clarification would be much appreciated.

Is this a compiler issue? Is it a memory leak? 
Although I'm not sure if it's actually the programs fault (and I apologise again for the terribly, terribly, messy code) this is the entire program;

```
int main(){

    char a;
    char c;

    int b = 0;
    int ans = 0;
    int err = 0;
    int isopen = 0;
    int deleteerror = 0;
    int god = 0;

    string info;
    string docinsert;
    string writeto;

    fstream notes;
    notes.open("notes.txt");

    cout << "What would you like to do to the text in this document?"<<endl<<"Over[W]rite, [R]ead, [D]elete." << endl;
    cin >> a;
    while (b != 1){
        if (err != 0){
            cout << "Please retry." << endl;
            cin >> a;
        }
        switch(a){
            case 'W':
            case 'w':
            b = 1;
            ans = 1;
            break;

            case 'R':
            case 'r':
            b = 1;
            ans = 2;
            break;

            case 'D':
            case 'd':
            b = 1;
            ans = 4;
            break;

            default:
            err = 1;
            cout << "An error has occurred." << endl;
}
}

    if (notes.is_open()){
    isopen = 1;
        switch (ans){

        case 1:
                cout << "Please write what you wish to put within the document.\nThis will DIRECTLY overwrite anything previously written.\nIn order to avoid unwanted characters, delete before overwriting." << endl << endl;
                cin.clear();
                cin.sync();
                getline(cin, docinsert);
                cout << endl;
                notes << docinsert;
                break;

        case 2:
                cout << endl << "This is what is currently written within the document:" << endl;
                getline(notes, info);
                cout << info << endl;
                break;

        case 4:
                cout << endl << "This is what is currently written within the document:" << endl;
                getline(notes, info);
                cout << info << endl;
                cout << endl << "Please confirm you wish to delete all information in this document.\n[D]elete, [C]ancel.\n\n";
                cin >> c;
                while (god != 2){
                    if (god = 1){
                        cout << "Please repeat input to verify.\n";
                        cin >> c;
                    }
                if (c == 'D' || c == 'd'){
                    notes.close();
                    ofstream notes("notes.txt");
                    cout << "File wiped." << endl;
                    return 0;
                }
                else if(c == 'C' || c == 'c'){
                    cout << "\nNo information removed.";
                    return 0;
                }
                else{
                    cout << "An error has occured.\n";
                    god = 1;
                }
        }

        default:
                cout << "An error has occurred.\n";
                return 0;
        }
    }

    else if(isopen != 1){
        cout << endl << "An error with reading the file has occurred.\nIf this error persists, create a text document\nnamed 'notes' in the root directory of this program.\n";

    }
}
```

Comment: When using a file name like `"notes.txt"` the file will be opened in the current directory, whatever that might be. In some places you might not have permission to create or write to files. If you use a full path for the file name, you will know exactly where the file ends up.

Comment: When you say "the file won't open and say that access is denied" do you means notes.txt won't open, or your program won't run? What does the access denied message look like?

Comment: This issue seems to have nothing to do with "notes.txt" as there are problems to execute the executable. Others seem to have to had the same issue using this particular tool suite (googled).

Comment: In stead of moving the DLLs just add the bin folder of the compiler to the path.

Comment: I don't quite understand how to do that jerry -- and besides, if it's an error with the dlls themself, would it even make a difference?

Answer (score -2):

fstream can read and write.  So you have to tell in the constructor what you are going to be using. 
like that: "fstream note("notes.txt", std::ios::out); or fstream note("notes.txt", std::ios::in);
You can't open the file before you specifyed the "mode".

Comment: I don't believe this is the problem, as all the functions work as I intended, it just occasionally happens. I believe this is what was mentioned previously, as access is denied to the file.

Additionally, if I use fstream instead of ifstream or ofstream, doesn't it initialise the file to be written to and read from?

Comment: fstream has default opening mode.